# Modifying nested JSONObject using json simple

Tags: java, json

Trying to modify values of a JSONObject within another JSONbject throws cannot find symbol error for method getJSONObject...

I can't use the getJSONObject method, a workaround for me was:

```
JSONObject Player = (JSONObject) PlayerTemp.get("Player");
Player.put("Language", "German");
```

However the following would not work:

```
JSONObject Player = PlayerTemp.getJSONObject("Player");
```

Here is my whole code example where I try to modify a value within a JSONObject that's nested within another JSONObject:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

     try (Reader reader = new FileReader("../resources/PlayerTemp.json")) {

         JSONObject PlayerTemp = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
         PlayerTemp.getJSONObject("Player").put("Language", "German");
         System.out.println(PlayerTemp.get("Player").toString());


     } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (ParseException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
```

}

```
error: cannot find symbol
PlayerTemp.getJSONObject("Player").put("Language", "German");
          ^
```

Comment: Which library do you use to parse `JSON`?

Comment: I use json.simple 1.1.1 as my library

Comment: That's a pretty old library - are you able to update?

Comment: for some reason it was the first I found when I started my project... Will update tomorrow and keep you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method called `getJSONObject` in [JSONObject](http://miamarti.github.io/HorusFramework/javadoc/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html) class, so you have to use `get()` with explicit type casting. If you want more advance methods like `getJSONObject` consider using `Gson` and `jackson`

```
JSONObject PlayerTemp = (JSONObject) parser.parse(reader);
JSONObject temp = (JSONObject) PlayerTemp.getJSONObject("Player");
temp.put("Language", "German");
```